# React JSX concat multiple {this.state} {this.props}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
{this.state.userFirst} //returns anime
{this.props.firstPlace} //returns netflix
{this.props.provider[0].netflixAnimeT //returns 495
```

My current Code is...

```
<p>
  {this.Capitalize(this.props.firstPlace)} has
  {`this.props.provider[0].${this.props.firstPlace}${this.Capitalize(
    this.state.userFirst || ""
  )}T`}
  {this.state.userFirst}
</p>;
```

```
Capitalize (str){
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
}
```

Currently outputs:

> Netflix has `this.props.provider[0].netflixAnimeT` anime

However, I want output of:

> Netflix has 495 anime

As I want it dynamic based on user ratings etc, how should I change my code in JSX?
Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @keikai I changed my post. Is this better?

Comment: I think you're just confused about JS object notation--you need to use bracket notation if you're dynamically accessing a property. Right now you're asking for a double-evaluation and that's not how it works.

Comment: ``{this.props.provider[0][`${this.props.firstPlace}${this.Capitalize(
    this.state.userFirst || ""
  )}T`]}``

Comment: @EmileBergeron perfect How do I choose yours as answer? This works perfectly.

Comment: Accept the duplicate candidate if you can.

Comment: @EmileBergerson Done. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace

```
{`this.props.provider[0].${this.props.firstPlace}${this.Capitalize(
  this.state.userFirst || ""
)}T`}
```

with

```
{this.props.provider[0].${this.props.firstPlace}${this.Capitalize(
  this.state.userFirst || ""
)}T}
```

The backtick makes it a literal string. You can also do

```
`${var} literal`
```

EDIT I missed some nuances about it, but this should work:

```
{`${this.props.provider[0]}.${this.props.firstPlace}${this.Capitalize(
  this.state.userFirst || ""
)}T`}
```

Comment: I tried this and got parsing error: unexpected token, expected "}"

Comment: This won't work either